# Optimizing Android app for blind people

Tags: android, talkback

I want to optimize my App for blind people. Since Android 4.4 (KitKat), there is the Talkback functionality available, which provides several ways for blind people to "see" whats on the screen.

I have one problem now with that function: It is reading aloud everything! Even if it is just a small icon or something. So my question:

**Can I configure what should be read aloud and what not?**

Are there maybe any XML configurations in the Layout which could be used to define what should be read aloud and what not?

Comment: The best suggestion I have is to add a "tag" to your XML elements.  With that you could identify not only what it's called, but what text should be read aloud.